# What is the best api/ tool for charts and graphs in Java EE web application?

Tags: jakarta-ee, charts

I know the question is subjective but I need to know what is the most appropriate api/tools for charts/graphs etc in the java web application.

We are working on the spring MVC application. We will need to show our data in charts, graphs etc. e.g. Whatever data that is being displayed on the page should be able to see chart of that or export it in excel etc.

We will also have lots of reports in our app which should be able to be exported to excel and pdf.

I have googled and found following few options like BIRT, Jasper reports, Google Charting API, JFrechart etc.

BIRT and JASPER looks too heavy.

Please help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[AM charts](http://www.amcharts.com/) which is one among the good ones, completely based on javascript which can used realtime monitoring or charting. also dygraphs is real cool javascript based charting library which you try [dygraphs](http://dygraphs.com/). we have used both in our company and it worked pretty well. both support json which is a real cool thing as javascript and json go hand in hand. i am not sure whether these tool support export to excel or not but definitely a cool one to represent the charts.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [ExtJS](http://www.sencha.com/products/extjs/) 4 from Sencha. It is a JavaScript framework. Here are few [examples](http://www.sencha.com/products/extjs/examples/#sample-3) from Sencha. You can have Charts, Graphs. But yeah! it does not support pdf/excel conversions. You may have to handle it from Server side. You can use third party libraries for that purpose.

Answer (score 0):

You can try [Highcharts](http://www.highcharts.com/demo/) for charting solution. For generating reports with data listings Jasper report API or BIRT should suffice.